Orthonormal and holonomic basis of polar coordinates
I am really struggling to make sense of example 1 in this pdf discussing orthonormal and coordinate basis of polar coordinates. I'd appreciate it if anyone can guide me step-by-step towards understanding.
When writing vector in polar coordinates, there are two kinds of basis: orthonormal basis $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}, \boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}\}$ and coordinate basis $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{r}, \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\}$.
It seems like $\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}=1\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}+0\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}=0\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}+1\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}$, and $\boldsymbol{e}_{r}=1\boldsymbol{e}_{r}+0\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}=0\boldsymbol{e}_{r}+1\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}$. In other words,
$$
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}&=1 & \boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}&=0 \\
\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}&=0 & \boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}&=1
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{e}_{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{r}&=1 & \boldsymbol{e}_{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}&=0 \\
\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{r}&=0 & \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}&=1
\end{align*}
$$
Is that correct? Then, metric in polar coordinates will be
$$g=\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{e}_{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{r} & \boldsymbol{e}_{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta} \\ \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{r} & \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
? I am not sure where this metric
$$g=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & r^2\end{pmatrix}$$
came from in the first place.
Also, I wonder how to compute orthonormal components of coordinate basis $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{r}, \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{e}_{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}&=1 & \boldsymbol{e}_{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}&=0 \\
\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat r}&=0 & \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat \theta}&=r
\end{align*}
$$

No, $e_\theta = re_{\hat\theta}$, so $e_\theta\cdot e_\theta = r^2$. What is the definition of $e_\theta$? It should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. What does that give you?
